# ng-click not working when I use onsen ui and $().append

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

When I use the JS to append a p tag into a `div`,the `ng-click` not working.My code as follows:

```
$("#newsArList").append("<p ng-click=\"myNavigator.pushPage(\'article.html\', { animation : \'slide\' } )\">Go To Article</p>");`
```

Actually，I

```
console.log("<p ng-click=\"myNavigator.pushPage(\'./www/article.html\', { animation : \'slide\' } )\">1234</p>");`the result is `<p ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('article.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">1234</p>
```

I just copy this one into the `<div id="newsArList"></div>`,and it working.

I don't know the reason for this situation. Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason is that angular needs to know that the DOM has changed, and to compile it, in order to do its magic. Just don't do that. Use angular as it's meant to be used. Put that snippet of HTML in your page, add an `ng-if="showStuff"` to the element, and set $scope.showStuff to true when you want the element to appear in the page.

Comment: Thanks you help me,but it cannot solve my question.My code as follows :`<div class="articleList" id="newsArList"   ng-if="showStuff">` and 

     `$("#newsArList").append("<p   ng-if=\"showStuff\" ng-click=\"myNavigator.pushPage(\'article.html\', { animation : \'slide\' } )\">1234</p>");`
  the result is the p tag will appear,but when I click it, it will not go to the article.html

Answer (score 0):

You use angular directive, so you must compile the code into the DOM:

`$("#newsArList").append('<p ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage(\'article.html\', { animation : \'slide\' } )">Go To Article</p>');`

`ons.compile($("#newsArList")[0]);`

As described [here](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html):

> ons.compile function converts your custom elements based HTML to a
>   normal DOM structure. Most browsers does not (yet) support custom
>   elements by default, you need to call the function every time to make
>   the magic happen.